# How do I handle a relationship with a NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: ios, core-data

Core data is already handling the relationship for me, do I need to build a new query to use the NSFetchedResultsController?

I have "Albums" that contain "Photos".

```
Album *anAlbum = [...getalbum...];
```

in the *cellForItemAtIndexPath: I'd like to do something with:

```
anAlbum.photos
```

However, I can't convert the indexPath to a NSSet member index. (obviously)

Without Core Data I'd typically just generate the query required myself. I'd like to make use of Core Data (again, obviously).

Comment: What do you want to display? Photos or album?

Comment: The "Photo" entity (anAlbum.photos is the relationship) contains the asset url. I have no issue with the displaying it was more of a concern of how do I use the NSSet (Core Data relationship) with the NSFectchedResultsController -- or direct with the view (collection/table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The "Photo" entity (anAlbum.photos is the relationship) contains the
>   asset url. I have no issue with the displaying it was more of a
>   concern of how do I use the NSSet (Core Data relationship) with the
>   NSFectchedResultsController -- or direct with the view
>   (collection/table).

First of all I would use a `NSFetchedResultsController` for this. This component is made to work in conjunction with tables and allows to load data in a lazy loading manner.
Second, the fetch request I would use should be run against `Photo` entity and not against `Album`. In other words, you should select all the photos that belong to a specific album.

Here the code, I would use...

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
        entityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"album == %@", anAlbum];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
        initWithKey:@"takeAt" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
        [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
            managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
            cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

So now in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you would use

```
Photo *photo = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
// access the album the photo belongs to
Album* album = photo.album;
```

You can grasp the main concepts for `NSFetchedResultsController` at [Core Data Tutorial for iOS: How To Use NSFetchedResultsController](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you're going to convert the set to an NSArray (maybe with NSSet's allobjects) and perhaps sort it or filter it with a NSSortDescriptor or NSPredicate or both.  Then, you can access the array by index using the index path section/row.

You can obviously use a NSMutableArray if that's what you need, but it is a pain to try to access NSSet items individually as you essentially have to enumerate them to find what you're looking for.  Just create an array.  Here's an example where I've done this:

```
NSArray *tableViewData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[album.photos allObjects]];
```

Then, you just access the tableViewData objects with:

```
UIImage *obj = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([tableViewData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], 0.50f);
```

Something like that.

Comment: I had considered that. I went to the CS193P demos and Paul Haggerty really did just build the NSFetchedResultsController from scratch -- as in he didn't use the "Photographer.photos" relationship from the data model. This is what is throwing me off.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but if you do a fetch without a predicate, you'll get all the data in the model; so, normally, you're going to use a predicate to filter the fetch.  But your predicate can filter on any field in the model.  The main point is that once you do your fetch, you can access any entity for the fetch results by just using the method indicated above.  Sorry, I'm not familiar with CS193P.  In practice, you're usually going to have a "helper" class that builds the fetched results controller and handles basic operations.  In my example, it would fetch the parent of the goal.

Comment: What I meant was... you already have "album.photos" -- why would I need to build a new query for the same data set?

Comment: I can't envision why you would do that.  Core Data handles the loading of those items as they're needed, not in the way, e.g., a tradition SQL query does.  So, once you have a set with the objects in them, core data takes care of it.  I don't know why your example is doing it that way, as it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I guess that's why I asked this question. I already have the set "album.photos" -- so how would I use that with an NSFetchedResultsController (for the purposes of a table/collection view)?

Comment: See edits to answer above; perhaps that will provide a bit more context for you.  Basically, you will get the set into an NSArray tableViewData, then, access the objects based on the row of index path.  But they'll be stored in core data as NSData items, so you'll then have to convert them to JPEGs or PNGs as shown.